# How to apply pre_get_posts to a custom query?

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

How can I apply `pre_get_posts` to a custom query?

For example, if I have:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query(...)
//code here
```

How can I apply the `pre_get_posts` for this `$custom_query`?

Answer (score 1):

For some use cases, couldn't you use `$query->get()` to target specific custom queries?

For example: say you've got a custom query for a `slider` post-type. Perhaps something like this?

```
function wpse64950_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_main_query() ) {
        if ( 'slider' == $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) {
            // This is a query of slider posts,
            // and isn't the main query;
            // Do something
        }
    }
    return;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse64950_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Granted, this will target *every* such `slider` post-type custom query; so it won't work in *every* case. But it *should* work in *some* cases.

Note: $query->get( 'post_type' ) could return an array (e.g. for a PODS custom post type). In that case something like if ( is_array($query->get(...)) && in_array('slider', $query->get(...)) ) would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

### pre_get_posts fires for every post query.

There is really no reason to apply it to a specific custom query.  If you don't want it to be applied to your custom query you need to make sure you are checking for [is_main_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query).

Comment: I want it to be applied to a custom query, but not on the main query.

Here's what i'm trying to achieve - i want to list posts with closed comments on one page, and i think it can be achieved with comment_status, 'open', using the pre_get_posts.

On the other hand, i want to do that with just one custom query, while the main query should remain intact.

Or is my logic wrong, and i'm missing something?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the necessary parameters to that specific query, since you're setting it up anyway?

Comment: @Pippin - how would i do that in my case? I want the main parameter to be are comments open or not?

so i want to create a query that will show only posts with closed or opened comments? How would i do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would do it in exactly the same way that you would with pre_get_posts. Do you know how to do it there (excluding the part about targeting a specific query)?

Comment: @Pippin
Would it look something like this?
`function comm_cl( $query ) {
  $query->set( 'comment_status', 'open' );
}`

I had this bit of code, https://gist.github.com/3709991 - it is working, but it's not working well with pagination. So that's really the problem i'm trying to solve, and i was hoping i can achieve it with pre_get_posts.

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.